# Unit tests for deprecated functions in R package cause warnings during check

Tags: r, deprecation-warning, testthat

I've deprecated several functions in my R package by including a `.Deprecated("new_function_name")` line at the start of the function.  I had full unit test coverage for those deprecated functions.  Now those tests produce warnings (because of the deprecation message) and muddy up the results of `testthat::test()` and `devtools::check().`

I could just delete the test coverage for deprecated functions, but it seems like as long as users can still call the functions, I should retain test coverage.  Is there a way I can keep the tests but avoid the clutter in the result of `check()`?  E.g., tell `testthat` to count them as passing if the `expect_equal()` still works, ignoring the deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but now the 'lifecycle' package offers a good method.  The documentation is clear and concise:

```
library(testthat)

mytool <- function() {
  deprecate_soft("1.0.0", "mytool()")
  10 * 10
}

# Forcing the verbosity level is useful for unit testing. You can
# force errors to test that the function is indeed deprecated:
test_that("mytool is deprecated", {
  rlang::local_options(lifecycle_verbosity = "error")
  expect_error(mytool(), class = "defunctError")
})

# Or you can enforce silence to safely test that the function
# still works:
test_that("mytool still works", {
  rlang::local_options(lifecycle_verbosity = "quiet")
  expect_equal(mytool(), 100)
})
```

You can use `tests/testthat/setup.R` to set the option globally for the tests.

Answer (score 7):

`.Deprecated` produces a warning. So you can always temporarily store the output and wrap that in a call to `expect_warning` or `suppressWarnings` if you don't care to test that it gives a warning.

```
my_dep_fun <- function(x){
   .Deprecated("my_new_fun")
   return(x+1)
}
```

Using this

```
> # This is what I expect you're doing right now
> expect_equal(my_dep_fun(3), 4)
Warning message:
'my_dep_fun' is deprecated.
Use 'my_new_fun' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
> 
> # If we store and use expect_warning we don't get the warning
> expect_warning(tmp <- my_dep_fun(3))
> expect_equal(tmp, 4)
> # Alternatively...
> suppressWarnings(expect_equal(my_dep_fun(3), 4))
>
```

Comment: This satisfies the primary goals of keeping the tests and yielding a clean sheet on `test()`.  I'd love to put this approach in a function so I could just change my tests from `expect_equal` to `expect_equal_deprecated` - would be cleaner to implement vs. updating each test like this.  But I tinkered with it and don't see a way, so maybe this is the best that can be done.